# Query Database for same day events

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I am trying to write a query for a hotel and I would love a list of rooms that guests are vacating the same day a new guest arrives.  I have a SQL query that tells me the name of the guest, the day the arrive, the day the leave, and the list of rooms they are using(this list is a string).  However, I want a smaller subset to be returned from SQL.  I only care about rooms that people are leaving and new guests are coming that day.  (Rooms that our housekeeping staff have a small window to turnover).  I could use some help conceptually on how to write the where clause of the query.  Also is this even possible in SQL, or would I need to do it in PHP?

Comment: This `list of rooms they are using(this list is a string).` is probably going to make a reasonable query a lot harder, it's also a denormalization issue in your database design. It might be good to post your existing database schema.

Comment: Yes, it's possible in SQL. Attach your code and schema to get further help. Right now your question is: "is it possible in sql or would I need to use PHP"?